# URL validation with jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin [URL validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/) for url validation. I ve added url:true to validate all valid URLs. The Validation plugin is great with the default functions it offers.

It accepts the urls started with http(s).

**For example https://www.yammer.com**

It throws error when the URL is not started with http(s)

**For example www.yammer.com.**

JS

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
        required: true,
        url: true
    }
  }
});
```

If the entered Url is not started with http(s), I want to add http(s) before validation. I don't want the URL to be validated with regular expressions. Because they are making lot of confusions. How can I add http/https before validation. If the entered URL is started with http(s) there is no problem.

Comment: So to be clear about what you're asking.  You want something that automatically prepends the `http://` or `https://` to the entered URL if it's missing?  How exactly is it supposed to know which protocol to add?  BTW, "data manipulation" is not really "data validation".

Comment: I would like to add http before jQuery validation. thats all

Comment: Fine, but that has nothing to do with jQuery Validate.

Comment: Got ans from @Rory MCCrossan. Understand the question fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the `url` rule. You would need to either:

- Append `http://` to the start of the URL field's value on blur if it wasn't already there
- Use a custom Regex
- Create a custom rule which does not require `https?://` for the field to be considered valid

Comment: I tried with so many regular expressions. But still haven,t find the the suitable one. So what I ve added jQuery validate plugin. It validates all URL properly. But should start with http(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#edit_profile").validate({
    rules: {
        website: {
             url: true,
        },
    },
    message:{
        website: {
            url: "Please enter valid url",
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and add at least a brief description of what you are doing and why this solves the problem in question.